# Typescript Get correct return type in subclass of abstract class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an abstract class with an abstract property and a function X that returns it, in the implementation class I only have to implement the property but calling X from the implementation class returns the type of the abstract prop instead of the implementation.

```
abstract class Test{
  protected abstract testProp: TestProp
  public getProp(): Test["testProp"]{
    return this.testProp
  }
}
type TestProp = {[value:string]:TestValues<any>} 
class TestValues<T> {
  value: T
  constructor(v:T){
    this.value = v
  }
  doSomething(){
    return true
  }
}

class TestImpl extends Test{
  protected testProp ={
    a: new TestValues<boolean>(true)
  }
}

var test = new TestImpl()
var prop = test.getProp()
```

Here prop is of type: `TestProp` instead of

```
{a: TestValues<boolean>}
```

What can I do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: What did yo do in order to check the type of your "prop"?

Comment: @NestorPerez The autocomplete feature of vscode didnt show any option with prop. and hovering prop shows TestProp as the type

Comment: Ideally `getProp()`'s return type would be `this["testProp"]` instead of `Test["testProp"]` (the latter is always just `TestProp` no matter what subclasses exist), but unfortunately according to [ms/TS#17362](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17362) you can't use indexed accesses on `protected` members this way.  If you can change your `protected` property to `public`, then [this just works](https://tsplay.dev/mx5jxW).  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer.  If not, how much would you be willing to refactor to achieve your goals?  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comment, i would like to keep it protected since it should be accessed only by that function, i can refactor anythingc so please if you know a way tell me

Comment: You can refactor to a class factory like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqv9RW).  It also seems to be possible to use `//@ts-ignore` to suppress the error on `this["testProp"]` if it's protected, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2K5VN), but suppressing compiler errors is usually not recommended because those errors often have weird additional effects.  Let me know if you want to see any of this as an answer.